# Can Promise.race use unnecessary memory?

Tags: promise

I have some code that returns either the result of an http request, or an error if the request isn't returned within 5 seconds:

```
const doRequest = () => request('http://www.google.com');
const doTimeout = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error(`Request timeout)), 5000));

return Promise.race([
  doRequest,
  doTimeout,
]);
```

In this case, if the request returns below 5 seconds the `doTimeout` continues to run until it naturally times out after 5 seconds. Is it a good idea to cancel the remaining Promises? For example,

```
const doRequest = () => request('http://www.google.com');

let timeout;
const doTimeout = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  timeout = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error(`Request timeout)), 5000);
});

const requestPromise = doRequest();

return Promise.race([
  requestPromise,
  doTimeout,
])
.then(response => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  requestPromise.cancel();
  return response;
})
.catch(err => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  requestPromise.cancel();
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: How will you cancel the Promise? I'm sure the proposal for cancelable Promises was [withdrawn](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancelable-promises). Or do you intend to utlize [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) for this?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that to be honest. Just wanted to cancel the SetTimeout if the request succeeded first, or, cancel the request (using `request-promise-native` library) if the request timed out. Is it worth doing this?